# python multithreading gives type error

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror, python-multithreading

Here is my piece of code, as I am trying to use multithreading

```
unipidA = ['list of data IDs with 6 characters each']

import threading;
from time import ctime()

def parse_data('give_data_id'):
    < code to parse data from server and
      each data ID has unique 6 character string e.g 'Q9NR22', 'Q86WR7' etc>

    print 'The data ', data_id, ' has been parsed'


def main():
    print 'Data Parsing Started at ', ctime()
    threads = []
    mylen = range(len(unipidA))
    for i in mylen:
        print unipidA[i]
        t = threading.Thread(target = parse_data ,args=(unipidA[i]))
        threads.append(t)

    for i in mylen:
        threads[i].start()

    for i in mylen:
        threads[i].join()

    print 'all done at:', ctime()
```

when I run it as:

```
>>> main() <Enter>
```

It gives the following error

```
>>> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
    TypeError: parse_data() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)
```

Can someone explain as the code is very primitive in multithreading but still I am unable to trace the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What's with passing in `'give_data_id'` to `parse_data()`? Did you mean `parse_data(give_data_id):`?

Comment: It is entry from the unipidA list the function will run like

parse_data ( unipidA[i] ) # i being any index

Comment: Yes, but you have quotes around your parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
args=(unipidA[i])
```

This does not what you think it does. The parentheses will not make it a tuple, in this case, it is just equivalent to `args=unipidA[i]`. And I guess in this case, it is a string of length 6.

To make a tuple which you can correctly pass as the `args` parameter, add a trailing comma:

```
t = threading.Thread(target = parse_data ,args=(unipidA[i],))
```

See also:

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> (1,)
(1,)
```